# How do I place my data on git with this error and connected with ssh?

Tags: git, github, ssh, terminal

I am trying to push to get files to git and it does not seem to be working. It says it cannot find the repository although it seems to exist.  Terminal command thread below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Bens-MacBook-Pro:week7 benmyhre$ cd site
Bens-MacBook-Pro:site benmyhre$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/benmyhre/Desktop/RubyProjects/week7/site/.git/
Bens-MacBook-Pro:site benmyhre$ git remote add origin git@github.com:bemyhre/site.git
Bens-MacBook-Pro:site benmyhre$ git commit -m'immapunch this screen'
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   README
#   contact.html
#   css/
#   img/
#   index.html
#   projects.html
#   untitled.html
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
Bens-MacBook-Pro:site benmyhre$ git add
Nothing specified, nothing added.
Maybe you wanted to say 'git add .'?
Bens-MacBook-Pro:site benmyhre$ git add .
Bens-MacBook-Pro:site benmyhre$ git push origin master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Bens-MacBook-Pro:site benmyhre$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi bemyhre! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Bens-MacBook-Pro:site benmyhre$
```

Comment: well, did you add any files to the index? First do `git add .` and then `git commit -m "something"` then do your push

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your git URL is not correct.

Go to the repository page in github and copy the clone URL in the middle right part.

Are you sure it is the same as the one you used?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Well, if you interpret the question as "Why does it not work?" the answer is "Your URL is not correct".